# Determine if a checkbox is checked using jquery on page load

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml

I am still pretty new to jQuery, so forgive me if this doesn't make sense the first round.

I have a set of checkboxes (allowed, not allowed, negotiable), that if you check allowed or negotiable it unhides another set of checkboxes via the onclick event.

The problem I am having is that when the page is refreshed, I want the second set of checkboxes to be visible if allowed or negotiable are checked. I'd like this to be done on page load, not through any click or change events if possible.

I have tried various suggestions to other issues with no luck.
eg: `if ($("#id_pets_0").attr("checked")==true)`

Is this possible?

If anyone has any alternatives to this, I'm game for that as well.

**UPDATE:**
This is what I have been attempting.

```
$(function() {
   if ($("#id_pets_0").attr("checked")==true) {
        $("#dogs").show();
        $("#cats").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#dogs").hide();
        $("#cats").hide();
    }
});
```

**UPDATE:**
This code does work. So I know that it is checking the checkboxes for the click events at least.

```
$(function() {
    $('input#id_pets_0').click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
        $("#id_pets_1").attr("checked", false);
        $("#dogs").show("slow");
        $("#cats").show("slow");
        return;
    }
    if ($("#id_pets_2").attr("checked")) {
        $("#dogs").show("slow");
        $("#cats").show("slow");
    }
    else {
        $("#id_dogs_0").attr("checked", false);
        $("#id_dogs_2").attr("checked", false);
        $("#id_cats_0").attr("checked", false);
        $("#id_cats_2").attr("checked", false);
        $("#dogs").hide("slow");
        $("#cats").hide("slow");
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all that answered. I would have thought those would have worked.

What I ended up doing was wrapping the show/hide options in a Django template `if` and use the context that was being passed. Since I was capturing the selection of `pets` I was able to then use the `if` to show or hide the `cats` and `dogs` selection section.

Answer (score 5):

You need to hook up to the `ready()` event of `document` unless you put all your scripting after the HTML.

Also, you need to use the `:checked` selector to determine if the checkbox is checked or not.

This should work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        if ($('#id_pets_0 :checked')) {
            alert('Hello');
        }
    });
```

Read more on the `:checked` selector: http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Comment: So the OP could do $("#id_pets_0").is(":checked");

Comment: I've actually tried this option. However I am only getting a False return even though the box is actually checked.

Comment: This should do it. I've tested it. :)

Comment: I tried something like this a few hours ago, but I gave yours a try as well. It worked initially, but when I cleared the form and reloaded the page the alert came up without the checkbox being checked. Could it be picking up anything from session variables or cookies?

Comment: no, this code wouldn't be affected by session (as it is client side) and there is no hidden cookie functionality underneath this.

Comment: I am really confused. It seems like it should be something simple.

Comment: I've added some additional code that I am using for click events that do work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/guanome/WzuMa/, it recognizes when the check box is check and when it isn't.

This website has a list of the possible ways to check if the checkbox is checked.
http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2008/12/how-to-check-if-checkbox-is-checked.html

Comment: Yes, I've been to that site as well. I've tried the .is and the .attr approaches. The problem is that they both seem to return `False` on a page refresh. They don't seem to detect that the box is actually checked.

Comment: On a page refresh or a postback? How is the checkbox being checked? In code?

Comment: The function that I posted in my question is currently how I am checking.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it in a document.ready function http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Replace the first line with this `$(document).ready(function() {`

Comment: Same thing. Doesn't recognize that the box is checked.

Comment: Unless you have something on the server side or javascript that is setting it to checked, it will always be `false` on the page load. Do you have server side code that you haven't posted?

Comment: Nothing server side. But the checkbox shows checked even on a refresh, so this makes me even more confused.

Comment: How do you refresh the page? And do you actually check the checkbox?

Comment: The page is either refreshed with search results, or if you just refresh the browser (F5). The check box is either selected to define the search or refine the search after the initial search. I don't use code to check the box, just click the box in the browser.

Comment: Is it an entire page reload or an ajax call that "refreshes" the page? Also if the input box is changed before you hit F5 and you are using Firefox it will sometimes carry over that visual value even though the dom has it as unchecked.

Comment: Going from the search page to the results page, it is not an ajax call. I am using Django, and it is just rendering a new page with a new template, but inheriting from the original search template. I have tried clearing the cache and using control-shift-r to reload the page and it gives me the same result. Now that I have thought about this a bit more, and you mention the issue with FF, although it happens in Chrome as well, I am wondering if it is an issue with the Django views and the templates.

Answer (score 0):

I know you want a jQuery response but have you tried it with just javascript? The statement is simple enough that you really don't gain much using jQuery.

```
if (document.getElementById("id_pets_0").checked) {
    $("#dogs").show();
    $("#cats").show();
}
else {
    $("#dogs").hide();
    $("#cats").hide();
}
```

Also are you absolutely certain that the checkbox is id_pets_0 and not the id of a wrapper around the checkbox?

Comment: That is the id of the input that the checkbox is specified. Using your method says that id_pets_0 is null...

Comment: If docoument.getElementById is returning null then jquery won't find the object either (thats what the $("#") selector uses). How are you rendering the checked checkbox on refresh?

Comment: I am doing nothing specific for the checkboxes. They are either checked or unchecked from previous.

Comment: $(function() {
    $('input#id_pets_0').click(function() { can be replaced with $('input#id_pets_0').live("click",function{} for simplicity

Comment: I found that if I run this
  function()
  {
  document.getElementById("#id_pets_0").checked=false
  }

before running the actual check things seem to work better.